Commit plumbing and commit porcelain do not match
Why after I finish the commit with the commands the plumbing files are still in the staging area.
Below are pictures of what I did, chronologically. The only thing I noticed is that I have nothing in .git/refs/heads/master, i.e. the HEAD of the branch is not specified, so I have a problem with the log command. I know that HEAD is needed only to control the previous commit to the next one, it is a pointer to the main node of the branch, so we have some linked list, but I don't see why the Git program doesn't see that the stage is committed. Some interpretation is that with git status he actually uses similar code as for git log to see what all went into the commit, so since he can't find it because there is no HEAD, he says that there are no commits yet.
status after set of plumbing commands
[work](https://i.sst[log
commit-tree after add file to tree](https://i.sstatic.net/z0kVZ25n.png)atic.net/v7AcUo7C.png)

Thanks if someone gives their solution, but I found my solution. The hypothesis I gave is correct Hypothesis: In order to perform control, git must, as it is not emphasized, for which starting point, all nodes (commit objects) are equal and of the same age and cannot decide who to access first, or not not even once. I solved the problem after defaulting to : git checkout ".git/refs/parentCommitName".That is, I set my own commit parent in the file parent commit name (HEAD).

The reason Git doesn't see your commits as being on the master branch is that they are not on the master branch; there are no commits on the master branch (it is "unborn", meaning that it is a name attached to no commit).
The way to create a root commit that is on the master branch using the plumbing commands is to use this pattern:
$ tree=$(git write-tree)
$ commit=$(echo 'Initial commit' | git commit-tree $tree)
$ git update-ref HEAD $commit

That update-ref step is what you left out. Until you do that, the master branch pointer is still just sitting there not pointing at anything ("unborn", as I said).
You would then do this for every subsequent commit, except that those commits would also have parents. Even though they do, you would still need to update the branch pointer.
The git commit command, of course, does the equivalent of all of that for you, under the hood. But you are exploring plumbing commands so you don't want to use it. :)

Thanks if someone gives their solution, but I found my solution. The hypothesis I gave is correct Hypothesis: In order to perform control, git must, as it is not emphasized, for which starting point, all nodes (commit objects) are equal and of the same age and cannot decide who to access first, or not not even once. I solved the problem after defaulting to : git checkout ".git/refs/parentCommitName".That is, I set my own commit parent in the file parent commit name (HEAD).
fixed yey

The trouble with this answer is that git checkout is not a plumbing commands, so have violated the terms of the experiment. :)
